# Display exact matches only with grep

Tags: unix, control-m

How can I display all jobs that ended OK only?

When I try the command below, it shows both OK and NOTOK since both have "OK"

```
ctmpsm -listall application | grep OK
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need a more specific expression. Try `grep " OK$"` or `grep "[0-9]* OK"`. You want to choose a pattern that matches what you want, but won't match what you don't want. That pattern will depend upon what your whole file contents might look like.

You can also do: `grep -w "OK"` which will only match a whole word "OK", such as "1 OK" but won't match "1OK" or "OKFINE".

```
$ cat test.txt | grep -w "OK"
1 OK
2 OK
4 OK
```

Comment: This worked fine.. but now I'm trying it with other commands such as `ctmpsm -listall application | grep -w "ABCD123"` there are lines display `ABCD123` and `ABCD123@` but I only want `ABCD123`

Comment: What *is* allowed after `ABCD123`? Just end of line? Space? Tab? Possibly any of those?

Comment: @aguas if there's nothing after it in the file (it's at the end of line), then you can use `grep ".* ABCD123$"` or just `grep " ABCD123$"`. If it is by itself on a line, then `grep "^\s*ABCD123\s*$"`.

Answer (score 24):

This may work for you

```
grep -E '(^|\s)OK($|\s)'
```

Comment: Can you explain the regular expressions here?

Comment: `(^|\s)` means beginning of line or space. `($|\s)` means end of line or space. So this would match "OK" as well as " OK " or " OK" or "OK ".

Answer (score 7):

**This worked for me**:

```
grep  "\bsearch_word\b"  text_file > output.txt  ## \b indicates boundaries. This is much faster.
```

or,

```
grep -w "search_word" text_file > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-v` switch to exclude strings.

This will grab any line ending in `OK` and then remove any line that includes `NOT`:

(If `OK` doesn't appear at the end, just remove the `$`.)

```
cat test.txt | grep 'OK$' | grep -v 'NOT'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this exact thing to test if my system has memcache installed. When I tried with grep it returned memcache but also memcached so your solution worked great!      php-memcache=$(php -m | grep 'memcache$' | grep -v 'NOT')

Comment: You want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Alex Misuno@hp4530s ~
$ cat test.txt
1 OK
2 OK
3 NOTOK
4 OK
5 NOTOK
Alex Misuno@hp4530s ~
$ cat test.txt | grep ".* OK$"
1 OK
2 OK
4 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command, because it works perfectly:

```
grep -ow "yourstring"

crosscheck:-
```

Remove the instance of word from file, then re-execute this command and it should display empty result.

Comment: Downvote: the `-o` is not pertinent and the `-w` is already provided in the highest-voted answer.

Comment: I disagree this actually provided a better result. When I used the search "xml" grep returned nothing past "xml" but it returned things that started before xml. Like "libxml". When I used this example it returned the exact match. php -m | grep -ow "xml"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grep -P '^(tomcat!?)' tst1.txt
```

It will search for specific word in txt file. Here we are trying to search word `tomcat`

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer so it reflects the question asked, that is how to distiguish OK from NOTOK. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across an issue in grep. I was trying to match the pattern x.y.z and grep returned x.y-z.Using some regular expression we may can overcome this, but with grep whole word matching did not help. Since the script I was writing is a generic one, I cannot restrict search for a specific way as in like x.y.z or x.y-z ..

Quick way I figured is to run a grep and then a condition check
var="x.y.z"
var1=`grep -o x.y.z file.txt`
if [ $var1 == $var ]
echo "Pattern match exact"
else
echo "Pattern does not match exact"
fi

https://linuxacatalyst.blogspot.com/2019/12/grep-pattern-matching-issues.html

Answer (score -2):

Search just "ok" word

```
grep "^ok$"
```

It means start with "o" and end with "k" and it must contain 2 characters, just it.

Comment: Do you know that `ctmpsm -listall application` outputs just the result on a line? I'm guessing the OP wants to find "ok" as a word, but print the whole line with other information too. (Which is easy as well; just use `grep -w`.)