# How can I get a whole word with grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to get the lines that contain a defined word with grep.

**Edit: The solution was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576826/4969982) one.**

I know that I can use the -w option, but it doesn't seems to do the trick.

For example: every word that contains my defined word separated by punctuation signs is included. If I look for dogs, it will show me lines that contain not only dogs word but also cats.dogs, cats-dogs, etc.

```
# cat file.txt
some alphadogs dance
some cats-dogs play
none dogs dance
few dog sing
all cats.dogs shout
```

And with grep:

```
# cat file.txt | grep -w "dogs"
some cats-dogs play
none dogs dance
all cats.dogs shout
```

Desired output:

```
# cat file.txt | grep -w "dogs"
none dogs dance
```

Do you know any workaround that allows you to get the whole word? I've tested it with \b or \< with negative results.

Thanks,
Eudald

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: `grep -w` would obviously not work here @triplee, it cannot be duplicated to the current question

Comment: `grep -w` fails because punctuation and end/start of line character are viewed as non-word characters; also even if it did work the implementation can be very slow

Comment: @lnian If you can find a better duplicate, I'll be happy to link to that. It's not like this is a terribly original question.  The currently designated duplicate does have answers which suggest anchors, though I agree that a better duplicate would be nice.

Comment: @tripleee maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-make-grep-only-match-if-the-entire-line-matches

Comment: Hello @tripleee , the existent problem is that the word exist in a string context, so I can't anchor neither beginning or end of line. I'm going to edit the question to make it more clear, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use the word-boundary anchors, in any version of `grep` you have installed

```
grep '^dogs$' file.txt
```

An excerpt from this [regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) page,

> Anchors
>
> [..] Anchors do not match any characters. They match a position. `^` matches at the start of the string, and `$` matches at the end of the string.[..]

Comment: Have you even tested it with the examples I provided? It doesn't work

Comment: @eudald_v: You didn't let us know with you sample updates, refer the timestamps to see. Not a problem, can you try `grep '[[:space:]]dogs[[:space:]]' file` which should solve your problem. let us know if it did

Comment: it only solves the example if the string has a space before, which in the sample happens but could not happen if the string is at the beginning or end of the sentence. Anyway, I edited the question again with the answer I finally found that works.

Comment: @eudald_v: Please understand, we can only test with the inputs you have provided. When you say it did;t work for cases other than having spaces, but you did not let us know such a input in your example.

Answer (score -1):

Try with -x parameter:

```
grep -x dogs file.txt
```

From `grep` manual:

> -x, --line-regexp
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)

NOTE: `cat` is useless when you pipe its output to `grep`

Comment: Have you even tested it with the examples I provided? It doesn't work